# Необходимость в десктопном ПО для создания сайта-визитки

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, webstorm

Хочу попробовать сделать небольшой сайт-визитку (в качестве пет-проекта для изучения front-end - как в пункте №1 https://www.upgrad.com/blog/front-end-project-ideas-topics-for-beginners/) с помощью онлайн-редакторов HTML + CSS + JavaScript, не устанавливая на свой компьютер какие-либо программы.

Т.е. в идеале, в системе должен быть запущен только браузер и всё.

Возможно ли это?
И стоит ли заморачиваться? Или это неразумная идея и стоит поставить, например, на ПК Visual Studio Code и выполнять вышеописанные действия там?

Или редактор кода тут недостаточен и нужно ставить IDE (например, WebStorm)?

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Можно все сделать в Notepad. Но зачем?

Comment: Если javascript будет небольшой, а не всякие react/vue,angular, не будет сборок всяких галпов вебпаков и пр, то можно и visual code. как я понимаю он бесплатный. Если же какие-то такие технологии использовать или с заделом на будущее - то сразу можно webstorm, чтобы не откладывать то, что и так будет в итоге

Comment: А можете попробовать https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, в идеале установить редактор кода или IDE, но можно использовать онлайн сервисы, например, repl.it ([this](https://repl.it)). Там нужно зарегистрироваться и создать проект. Выберите язык HTML/CSS/JS